# invalid argument delphi

Tags: delphi

I get an error while saving a string. the error is:
prject prKlanten.exe raised exeption class EVariantInvalidArgError with message 'invalid argument'.

```
    var
  fmOrder: TfmOrder;
  orderid: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
uses unDm, unInloggen, unKlant, unKeuze, unbeheer, unAccount, unOrderChange;

procedure TfmOrder.btOpslaanOClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    dm.atOrder.open;
    dm.atOrder.Append;
    dm.atOrder ['OrderStatus']             := ('Aangemeld');
    dm.atOrder ['klantID']                 := fminloggen.userid;
    dm.atOrder ['OrderDatum']              := leOphaalDatum.text;
    dm.atOrder ['Opmerkingen']             := leOpmerkingen.text;
    fminloggen.userid                      := dm.atOrder ['KlantID'];
    dm.atOrder ['OrderID']                 := fmOrder.orderid ;   
    dm.atOrder.post;
    fmOrderChange.ShowModal;
  end;
end.
```

the line :

```
dm.atOrder ['OrderID']                 := fmOrder.orderid ;
```

gives the error. I spelled everything correctly en the fminloggen.userid does works.

does anyone know what the problem is.

thanks in advance!

Jasper

I did the same in an other form:

```
public
  var inlognaam : string;
  userid    : string;
end;

var
  fmInloggen: TfmInloggen;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses unKlant, unbeheer, unaccount, unKeuze,unDm;

procedure TfmInloggen.BTinloggenClick(Sender: TObject);

var Gevonden: boolean;
  begin
    dm.atInlog.open;
      Gevonden := false;
    while (not Gevonden) and (not dm.atInlog.eof) do
      begin
          if dm.atInlog['email'] = leUser.Text
          then
        begin
         Gevonden := true ;
         fminloggen.inlognaam := dm.atInlog['email'];
         fminloggen.userid    := dm.atInlog['KlantID'];
        end
          else
        dm.atInlog.Next
      end;

  if Gevonden and (dm.atInlog['Password'] = lePassword.text)
    then
     if dm.atInlog['Autorisatie'] = '1'
       then
       begin
          fmKlant.Caption := dm.atInlog['email'];
          fmKeuze.ShowModal;
       end
        else if dm.atInlog['Autorisatie'] = '2'
         then
         begin
           fmKlant.Caption := dm.atInlog['email'];
           fmBeheer.ShowModal;
         end;
    dm.atInlog.Close;
  end;
```

except this is with userid

Comment: Are you sure this is correct : ('Aangemeld')

Comment: What type is fmOrder.orderid & ['OrderID']?

Comment: @simaWB yes that is correct, that is being recorded in the database
@Lieven fmOrder.orderid is an string orderid: string; as you can see.
['orderID'] is a colomn in a database

Comment: As a general remark on your code: I see too many global variables, forms accessing data in other forms, and too many string literals. You have a little maze that makes it very hard to find errors. Invest some time to refactor your application to give it more structure, and it will save you a truckload of time maintaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your working example you have:

```
public
  var inlognaam : string;
  userid    : string;
end;
```

Assuming from this that they are both fields in a form declaration.

In your non-working examply you have:

```
  var
fmOrder: TfmOrder;
orderid: string;
```

fmOrder seems to be the IDE generated instance variable of the form. If orderid follows that then it can't be a field of the form declaration.

Are you sure that you have orderid declared as a field in the TfmOrder form declaration? As you say in your comment to @BugFinder's answer that you cannot insert the `myStringVar := fmOrder.orderId;` line, I suspect that you get a compiler error on that and that could well be because orderId is not a member field of fmOrder...

Comment: Yes i declared : 
`var
  fmOrder: TfmOrder;
  orderid: string;`


`var Inlognaam:string; `stands appart from this?
or I am getting it wrong.

Comment: @Jasper: Not sure what you are telling/asking in your comment. I don't want to sound condescending, but do you understand when something is part of a class declaration and when not and how that affects what you can and can't do? If the declaration of orderid is between the lines with `TfmOrder = class(TForm)` and the first `end;` after that, then it is part of the TfmOrder class and you can use fmOrder.orderid. If orderid is declared after the first `end;` after the  `TfmOrder = class(TForm)` line, then it isn't part of the class declaration and you cannot use `fmOrder.orderid`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that and this point fmOrder is not invalid?
Debug it, and follow the lines through, check that dm.atOrder['OrderID'] is valid, as well as fmOrder is valid. It would need to be one of the two.

Comment: fmOrder is the form, I checked it, it is valid. 
dm.atOrder['OrderID'] is deffinitly an column in a atOrder.

I have done this the same way as with userid and that worked :s

Comment: @Jasper, we can't debug your code remotely but you could split the line into two parts. `dm.atOrder['OrderID'] = 'Test';` and `myStringVar := fmOrder.orderId;`. Depending on what line fails now, we can already exclude some possibilities.

Comment: the first line fails. 
could not convert variant of type string into type boolean

also i cant insert the line myStringVar := fmOrder.orderId;

Comment: @Jasper, Did you *declare* `myStringVar: string`?

Comment: @Jasper, anyway it doesn't matter. The error clearly indicates that `dm.atOrder['OrderId']` is defined as a Boolean fields io a string field.

Comment: @lieven, yes that gives the error indeed. But in my database they are both numbers. 1 is auto number but doesnt mind. I did it the same way with userid and that works

Comment: @Jasper, sorry, I goofed up. It should have been `dm.atOrder['OrderID'] = 666;` and `myIntegerVar := fmOrder.orderId;`

Comment: while fmOrder maybe the variable of the form, but is it actually created, it maynot be however the instance of the form you're using, if you're referring to a local variable then dont put the fmOrder part on it, just in case.

Comment: @Lieven, with 666 it gives an other error: EDatabaseError with message 'Field'orderid'cannot be modified'

@bugfinder you mean like this? dm.atOrder ['OrderID']                 := orderid ;

It gives an invalid argument error.

Comment: @Jasper, I would say there's your answer? Is OrderID perhaps an Identity field in the database?

Comment: @Lieven, orderid is indeed a primary key in the database. however i am trying to save that id in a variable. Wich i want to post in an other table.

Comment: @Jasper, you are not saving it in a variable, you are assigning it to the field (wich is most likely readonly).

Comment: @Lieven, how am I not saving it into a variable? I am assigning it to orderid wich is a string ? `var
fmOrder: TfmOrder;
orderid: string;`
And i am saving it with this line to it? `dm.atOrder ['OrderID']                 := orderid ;`
or what am i missing?

Comment: @Jasper. All forms in delphi by default get a variable put in the delcaration, however, in the calling form instead of using your fmOrder, you could have done x:=TfmOrder.Create(..);  as a result, fmOrder is invalid.

Comment: @bugfinder, It does work with the userid? with the second example in my question. There does the variable works

Comment: @Jasper, but thats a different form! If thats your main form, chances are you let delphi auto create it, and it is using that variable.

Comment: Well, putting it in another form may work, but partly its the design you need to think more of. Personally, for delphi, Other than the main form created at startup, I actually remove all those self added variables for forms just to prevent such issues